# MS edge onscroll laggy

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I have 2 divs each with a table. Trying to keep them in synch when the bottom div scrolls. I have onscroll event bound and when it triggers I adjust the first tables position. Works fine in ie11, chrome, firefox. In edge there is a huge delay when scrolling before the onscroll event fires and there is a noticeable delay. Eventually the 2 tables positions get synched up but it looks horrible for half a second until the onscroll event finally triggers. Any ideas how to fix it?

https://jsfiddle.net/hoffm263/Lcxv3164/6/#&togetherjs=AVVaUkC93B

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#d1").on("scroll", function(e) {
    console.log(new Date());
    //adjust h1 position
    $("#h1").scrollLeft($(e.target).scrollLeft());
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  border: solid black 1px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: normal;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

tbody {
  display: block;
}

#h1 {
  width: 317px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#d1 {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 317px;
}

#d1 table {
  width: 400px;
}

#h1 table {
  width: 417px;
}

#h1 td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
}

#h1 td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

#h1 td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 267px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

#d1 td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
}

#d1 td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

#d1 td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div id="h1">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>11111fasdfas</td>
        <td>2 222</td>
        <td>33333333</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="d1">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>111asfasdfasdfafasdasdf11 adf adf a df 111</td>
        <td>2222 sdaf dsd f222 222</td>
        <td>33333 da fsfd as333</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>111asfasdfasdfafasdasdf11 adf adf a df 111</td>
        <td>2222 sdaf dsd f222 222</td>
        <td>33333 da fsfd as333</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>111asfasdfasdfafasdasdf11 adf adf a df 111</td>
        <td>2222 sdaf dsd f222 222</td>
        <td>33333 da fsfd as333</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>111asfasdfasdfafasdasdf11 adf adf a df 111</td>
        <td>2222 sdaf dsd f222 222</td>
        <td>33333 da fsfd as333</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>111asfasdfasdfafasdasdf11 adf adf a df 111</td>
        <td>2222 sdaf dsd f222 222</td>
        <td>33333 da fsfd as333</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: You need to initialize `x` to -2.4 on line 12.... Just kidding! We can't actually help you with code that we can't see. Please include a [mcve] in the question. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Comment: tryng to figure out how to post the fiddle ... getting syntax issues just adding the link. used the link thingy in the editor but still showing some error when updating...

Comment: Note that there is likely no need for a link to JSFiddle if you use the instructions I posted for a Stack Snippet...

Comment: I guess that is good since I can paste a link to google but not to my fiddle. I will have no choice.

Comment: I pasted code sample. But of course when I test it with the "run snippet" it is not as bad. When I run this locally there is a very noticable delay in the top and bottom tables. In chrome, IE11, ff there is no delay at all

Comment: `[passive: false}`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters

Comment: I think the little difference is due to the different behavior of different browsers. We can't change the browser design so I think the alternative way is to accept the difference if it doesn't affect the usage.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your event listener is triggering multiple times. That causes the lag in the browser as your code is trying to do a lot of work in small amount of time. When you add scroll events you need to use throttle or debounce functions => https://www.npmjs.com/package/throttle-debounce

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will try that and get post back later. I added the log statement in my code already to see how often the onscroll was getting triggered and from what I can see it doesnt trigger very often. When I first start dragging it triggers every .5 seconds. Seems like when I drag slowly it triggers more frequently. Anyway I will try the debounce idea.

Comment: I added a throttle and now chrome, ff, ie11 are laggy like edge. Edge is about the same. Also I can see now in edge the issue seems to be disappearing and reappearing sporadically. Bout to say F edge and just not care. Its for internal app and only needs to run on chrome. Just thought I would make an effort at cross browser compatibility but have lost the ability to care. Thank you MS for another garbage browser. How are they not bankrupt yet.